# Take first non-0 value or last 0 value if that's all there is

Tags: r, dplyr, data-cleaning

Ciao,

Here is my replicating example.

```
HAVE <- data.frame(ID=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6),
                   ABSENCE=c(NA,NA,NA,0,0,0,0,0,1,NA,0,NA,0,1,2,0,0,0),
                   TIME=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3))


WANT <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                   ABSENCE=c(NA,0,1,0,1,0),
                   TIME=c(NA,3,3,2,2,3))
```

The tall data file HAVE is the one I need to convert to WANT. So essentially for each ID I need to identify the first non-zero value and that value goes into the data file WANT. If all values of absence is NA than TIME is NA. If all values of ABSENCE is 0 then I report the last possible row in WANT (as reflected in the TIME variable)

This is my attempt:

```
WANT <- group_by(HAVE,ID) %>% slice(seq_len(min(which(ABSENCE > 0), n())))
```

but I do not know how to take the last of the 0 rows if there are only 0s.

Comment: Seems there are some problems with the `WANT` data.frame, `length(WANT$TIME)` is different than the other vectors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(HAVE)

res = unique(HAVE[, .(ID)])

# look up first ABSENCE > 0
res[, c("ABSENCE", "TIME") := unique(HAVE[ABSENCE > 0], by="ID")[.SD, on=.(ID), .(ABSENCE, TIME)]]

# if nothing was found, look up last ABSENCE == 0
res[is.na(ABSENCE), c("ABSENCE", "TIME") := unique(HAVE[ABSENCE == 0], by="ID", fromLast=TRUE)[.SD, on=.(ID), .(ABSENCE, TIME)]]

# check
all.equal(as.data.frame(res), WANT)
# [1] TRUE

   ID ABSENCE TIME
1:  1      NA   NA
2:  2       0    3
3:  3       1    3
4:  4       0    2
5:  5       1    2
6:  6       0    3
```

I'm using data.table since the tidyverse does not [and never will](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/425) support sub-assignment / modifying only rows selected by a condition (like the `is.na(ABSENCE)` here).

If there two rules can be made more consistent with each other, this should be doable in a left join or a single group_by + slice as the OP attempted, though. Okay, here's one way, though it looks impossible to debug:

```
HAVE %>% 
  arrange(ID, -(ABSENCE > 0), TIME*(ABSENCE > 0), -TIME) %>% 
  distinct(ID, .keep_all = TRUE)

  ID ABSENCE TIME
1  1      NA    3
2  2       0    3
3  3       1    3
4  4       0    2
5  5       1    2
6  6       0    3
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `data.table` as well, based on subsetting the `.I` row counter:

```
WANT <- HAVE[
  HAVE[,
    if(all(is.na(ABSENCE))) .I[1] else
    if(!any(ABSENCE > 0, na.rm=TRUE)) max(.I[ABSENCE==0], na.rm=TRUE) else
    min(.I[ABSENCE > 0], na.rm=TRUE),
    by=ID
  ]$V1,
]
WANT[is.na(ABSENCE), TIME := NA_integer_]

#   ID ABSENCE TIME
#1:  1      NA   NA
#2:  2       0    3
#3:  3       1    3
#4:  4       0    2
#5:  5       1    2
#6:  6       0    3
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are two approaches using `dplyr` and custom functions. Both rely on the data being sorted by `TIME`.

## Filter Approach

```
# We'll use this function inside filter() to keep only the desired rows
flag_wanted <- function(absence){

  flags <- rep(FALSE, length(absence))

  if (any(absence > 0, na.rm = TRUE)) {
  # There's a nonzero value somewhere in x; we want the first one.

    flags[which.max(absence > 0)] <- TRUE

  } else if (any(absence == 0, na.rm = TRUE)) {
  # There's a zero value somewhere in x; we want the last one.

    flags[max(which(absence == 0))] <- TRUE

  } else {
  # All values are NA; we want the last row

    flags[length(absence)] <- TRUE

  }
  return(flags) 
}

# After filtering, we have to flip TIME to NA if ABSENCE is NA
HAVE %>%
  arrange(ID, TIME) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(flag_wanted(ABSENCE)) %>%
  mutate(TIME = ifelse(is.na(ABSENCE), NA, TIME)) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 6 x 3
     ID ABSENCE  TIME
  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
1    1.     NA    NA 
2    2.      0.    3.
3    3.      1.    3.
4    4.      0.    2.
5    5.      1.    2.
6    6.      0.    3.
```

The `filter()` step reduces the dataframe to the rows you need. Since it doesn't modify the TIME values, we need to `mutate()` as well.

## Summarize Approach

```
# This function captures the general logic of getting the value of one variable
# based on the value of another
get_wanted <- function(of_this, by_this){

  # If there are any positive values of `by_this`, use the first
  if (any(by_this > 0, na.rm = TRUE)) {

    return( of_this[ which.max(by_this > 0) ] )

  }

  # If there are any zero values of `by_this`, use the last
  if (any(by_this == 0, na.rm = TRUE)) {

    return( of_this[ max(which(by_this == 0)) ] )

  }  
  # Otherwise, use NA
  return(NA)     
}

HAVE %>%
  arrange(ID, TIME) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(TIME = get_first_nz(of_this = TIME, by_this = ABSENCE),
            ABSENCE = get_first_nz(of_this = ABSENCE, by_this = ABSENCE))

# A tibble: 6 x 3
     ID  TIME ABSENCE
  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1    1.   NA      NA 
2    2.    3.      0.
3    3.    3.      1.
4    4.    2.      0.
5    5.    2.      1.
6    6.    3.      0.
```

The order of summarization matters because we're overwriting variables, so this approach is risky. It only produces the output `WANT` if you summarize `TIME` and then `ABSENCE`.